# Aletrnate for 'unset' CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a div contains following CSS.

HTML

```
<div class="fixed-bottom pull-right" id="supdiv" onClick="myfunction()">Support</div>
```

CSS

```
#supdiv
 {
  left: unset !Important;
  z-index: 999999999;
  display:none
}
```

In Chrome

[image]

In IE

[image]

Its working fine on Chrome but expand div width in IE.

So is there any solution to this problem.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also note that `unset` is not supported by IE - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset

Comment: Thanks, @Paulie_D, I know unset it not supported by IE, could you provide solution or alternative for this.

Comment: There isn't one unless you can show us what it is you are trying to do. See my first comment.

Comment: okay, @Paulie_D I edited my question. Hope now you can easily understand.

Comment: Where's the HTML?

Comment: @LionelW I added now.

Comment: There must be more to it that the single HTML element. **What are you trying to do**? - Demonstrate *that*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks All of you guys.

I found a simple solution to my problem.

Its very simple infect. I just change the following code.

OLD CODE:

```
left: unset !Important;
```

NEW CODE:

```
left: auto;
```

Comment: From your last post. I can see that you had solved your issue. I suggest you to mark that post as an answer may help other community member in future.

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow, how can I do it?

Comment: you can see an icon for ☑ in your answer. you can click on it to mark the answer. see Image here...https://i.postimg.cc/5t9HrN4M/32.png

Comment: Okay buddy thanks, but I can't accept my answer in less than two days.